# Failed to create Commit object after receiving it from GitHub API

Tags: android, api, github, pojo

I am trying to receive commits from my GitHub repository.

When I manualy put the request url into browser I am reveiving the JSON object, but when I am trying to do this in my Android app - I am receiving nothing.

Maybe my POJO is not correct ?

Here is the request URL (for example): https://api.github.com/repos/Poyarkov95/AutoRate/commits

Here is Commit class:

```
public class Commit extends RealmObject {

    @SerializedName("repo_name")
    private String mRepoName;

    @SerializedName("author")
    private Author mAuthor;

    @SerializedName("message")
    private String mMessage;

    public Commit() {
    }

    public Commit(String mRepoName, Author mAuthor, String mMessage) {
        this.mRepoName = mRepoName;
        this.mAuthor = mAuthor;
        this.mMessage = mMessage;
    }

    @NonNull
    public String getRepoName() {
        return mRepoName;
    }

    public void setRepoName(@NonNull String repoName) {
        mRepoName = repoName;
    }

    @NonNull
    public Author getAuthor() {
        return mAuthor;
    }

    public void setAuthor(@NonNull Author author) {
        mAuthor = author;
    }

    @NonNull
    public String getMessage() {
        return mMessage;
    }

    public void setMessage(@NonNull String message) {
        mMessage = message;
    }
}
```

Author class:

```
public class Author extends RealmObject {

    @SerializedName("name")
    private String mAuthorName;

    public Author() {
    }

    public Author(String mAuthorName) {
        this.mAuthorName = mAuthorName;
    }

    @NonNull
    public String getAuthorName() {
        return mAuthorName;
    }

    public void setAuthorName(@NonNull String authorName) {
        mAuthorName = authorName;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**:
Code for receiving data:

```
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Observable<List<Commit>> receiveCommits(String userName, String repoName){
        return ApiFactory.getGithubService().commits(userName, repoName)
                .flatMap(commits -> {
                    Realm.getDefaultInstance().executeTransaction(realm -> {
                        realm.delete(Commit.class);
                        realm.insert(commits);
                    });
                    return Observable.just(commits);
                })
                .onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> {
                    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
                    RealmResults<Commit> realmResults = realm.where(Commit.class).findAll();
                    return Observable.just(realm.copyFromRealm(realmResults));
                })
                .compose(RxSchedulers.async());

    }
```

Service interface:

```
@GET("/repos/{user}/{repo}/commits")
    Observable<List<Commit>> commits(@Path("user") String user, @Path("repo") String repo);
```

Class for Retrofit configuration:

```
public final class ApiFactory {

    private static OkHttpClient sClient;

    private static volatile GithubService sService;

    private ApiFactory() {
    }

    @NonNull
    public static GithubService getGithubService() {
        GithubService service = sService;
        if (service == null) {
            synchronized (ApiFactory.class) {
                service = sService;
                if (service == null) {
                    service = sService = buildRetrofit().create(GithubService.class);
                }
            }
        }
        return service;
    }

    public static void recreate() {
        sClient = null;
        sClient = getClient();
        sService = buildRetrofit().create(GithubService.class);
    }

    @NonNull
    private static Retrofit buildRetrofit() {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BuildConfig.API_ENDPOINT)
                .client(getClient())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }

    @NonNull
    private static OkHttpClient getClient() {
        OkHttpClient client = sClient;
        if (client == null) {
            synchronized (ApiFactory.class) {
                client = sClient;
                if (client == null) {
                    client = sClient = buildClient();
                }
            }
        }
        return client;
    }

    @NonNull
    private static OkHttpClient buildClient() {
        return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(LoggingInterceptor.create())
                .addInterceptor(ApiKeyInterceptor.create())
                .build();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**:
Use receiveCommits():

```
public class CommitsPresenter {

    private final LifecycleHandler mLifecycleHandler;
    private final CommitsView commitsView;

    public CommitsPresenter(LifecycleHandler mLifecycleHandler, CommitsView commitsView) {
        this.mLifecycleHandler = mLifecycleHandler;
        this.commitsView = commitsView;
    }

    public void init(String repositoryName){
        KeyValueStorage keyValueStorage = RepositoryProvider.provideKeyValueStorage();
        String userName =  keyValueStorage.getUserName().toBlocking().first();
        RepositoryProvider.provideGithubRepository().receiveCommits(userName, repositoryName)
        .doOnSubscribe(commitsView::showLoading)
        .doOnTerminate(commitsView::hideLoading)
        .compose(mLifecycleHandler.load(R.id.commits_request))
        .subscribe(commitsView::showCommits, throwable -> commitsView.showError());
    }
}
```

Method init() calls when view is created:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_commits);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        mLoadingView = LoadingDialog.view(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this));
        mRecyclerView.setEmptyView(mEmptyView);

        mAdapter = new CommitsAdapter(new ArrayList<>());
        mAdapter.attachToRecyclerView(mRecyclerView);

        String repositoryName = getIntent().getStringExtra(REPO_NAME_KEY);

        LifecycleHandler lifecycleHandler = LoaderLifecycleHandler.create(this, getSupportLoaderManager());
        presenter = new CommitsPresenter(lifecycleHandler, this);
        presenter.init(repositoryName);
    }
```

Comment: And where is code actually fetches this JSON? You showed just realm classes.

Comment: As per my understand Realm doesn't support @SerializedName("whatever"). Could you try removing all the SerialisedName annot and rename the fields with the exact key name (key name from json response). Eg: first field from Commit class will be `private String repo_name;`

Comment: @Divers I have updated the topic.

Comment: @Andrew show the code where you use `receiveCommits` method.

Comment: @Divers ok, I added it

Comment: I see that you have `LoggingInterceptor`, so what do you see in logs? Do you receive json? Did you use debugger? What is your `commits` object inside `receiveCommits` method inside `flatMap`?

Comment: Logs are showing that I am receiving the response, and I have the Commit object - but fields for this object is null all of them. And I started the topic with the point that maybe pojo object is wrong, becase I thougth that it's inittialize wrong.

Comment: @Divers maybe the json from response is not matches with this pojo, is this even a case ?